# Name of Vegetarian that Eats Insects

Tags: language, vegetarian

There are different type of vegetarians, such as Lacto ovo vegetarian, Lacto vegatarian, and Vegan. Some cultures eat insects, which may violate the naming of these rules. I'm curious if there is a name for vegetarians that eat insects too.

Comment: "Insectivore" seems too obvious...

Comment: This might be better on [english.se], since word requests are kind of their thing. But you might also want to clarify whether you're asking for a commonly-understood word/phrase, or something obscure that won't actually help you communicate.

Comment: Insectivore looks to be as close as the language gets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnivore#Classification Paragraph 3.  (Scientists communicate too, Jefromi.)

Comment: If someone called themselves an insectivore, I'd assume they ate only insects.

Comment: As a note, this person is not a vegetarian - the insects are killed in order to be eaten,  and death of a living creature is usually the absolute cutoff for if something can be vegetarian, or cannot be.  The term would probably be more like "pescatarian" (is allowed to eat fish), which denotes a person with a restricted diet that nevertheless *does not fit* the vegetarian category - note that "pescatatrian" is its own, independent, term, "ovo" or "lacto" would be used as a modifier to "vegetarian", for subcategories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logic suggests *entomotarian* by analogy with *pescatarian* and *entomo-* as a root for words related to insects. Specifically *entomophagy* is the practice of eating insects.

I'm not alone in suggesting this: [a blog called the culinary linguist users of at least in passing, and there are other hits on Google](https://theculinarylinguist.wordpress.com/tag/entomophagy/)

Answer (score 3):

The term is "not vegetarian".

The definition of vegetarian is someone who does not eat animals. Insects are animals, so you are not vegetarian if you eat them.

Comment: "Liar" would be suitable too

Answer (score 1):

What about "insecto-vegetarian"? in analogy with "lacto-vegetarian" and "ovo-lacto-vegetarian".

Comment: If you want to advertise a proposal here, feel free to add it to our community ads post [here](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2152/community-promotion-ads-2016).